# Transfer from Italy to Turkey still pending

Tags: italy, swift, turkey

I made a transfer on 02/07/2019 from Italian EUR account to a Turkish Eur account. The status at that time was empty but the very next day the status became as "Preso in carico" which means taken charge. If we count the days from Wednesday onwards, it makes 6 working days. I also did not see any amount deducted from my account but a few hours back I see that my available balance shows the wrong amount. The amount has not appeared yet in my statement and does not show there. I have called the helpline too but no help. Does this mean that the transaction is still in process?

Answer (score 1):

In general there are only two sets of people that can help give you useful information - the sending bank and the receiving bank.

I have always started with the receiving bank, and ask them for an update and timeline. For instance I once called a bank that said they saw the incoming transfer in the system, so they had it, and said they try to complete all transactions within X hours - of course it had already been X + 8 hours when they said that, but basically that just meant that they had the money and they would get to it when they get to it. I asked for a time frame and planned to call back if they didn't do it, but they said end of day and they ended up doing so with 1 hour to spare.

If the receiving bank can't confirm they see/received the transaction, call the issuing bank and see what is up on their side. Confirm all relevant numbers to ensure there is no error in the transaction, on your end or theirs.

Once you have relevant updates from them, about the only thing you can do is wait, or try to annoy them into doing their job more quickly - calling the company or individual branch, asking for an update/timeline, and then calling back again when that time is near or passed. Escalate to higher levels of management as the screw up seems to be more severe.

About the only time you can usefully do something else is when there is an officially published timeline that they have wildly violated, such as promising 24-48 hours but taking more than a week or two. You can then try to complain to a relevant regulating authority if your continued calls and requests to escalate don't work, but banks are pretty resilient to small-scale individual complaints, and most regulating authorities are slow enough that they will only help in severe situations or if you are seeking some sort of recompense that the law requires (such as a refund of fees, etc., and this will take weeks or months generally).

Comment: Thank you for the information. The amount was not deducted from my account on the successful transfer? Now somehow after 6 days the total available balance shows a reduced amount? I already called my bank and they said it can take up to 7-10 days. Tomorrow its going to be the 7th day haha

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds Also, they may be counting working days, not elapsed natural days - so weekends and bank holidays don’t count.

Comment: Yup. I am counting working days.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on individual luck, a cross country money transfer using bank service is never pleasant. Because there are more than 2 levels of clearing system involved and nobody can tell you which level mess up.

For any individual wants to transfer money to foreign bank account, always using peer-to-peer money transfer services such as transferwise and its [alternatives](https://www.finder.com/sites-like-transferwise).

They offer lower rates and faster clearing (In fact, money change hand locally than wired over). Those services are perfectly legal and abide to local law.